# How to match changing criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have criteria that I'm trying to match, but that criteria will change over time. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
bool masterBool = false;

bool isTrue = true;
bool isAlsoTrue = true;
bool isTrueToo = true;

if (isTrue && isAlsoTrue && isTrueToo)
{
    masterBool = true;  
}
```

Like I said though, the criteria will be altered from time to time. Maybe isTrue  no longer needs to be true but a new criterion needsToBeTrue is introduced. This would require adding and removing variables in the method and the compound conditional. I'm wondering if there is another way to approach this problem? This way seems sloppy to me.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe through the use of `Predicate<T>` or an list of predicates?

Comment: Maybe you could pass in a list of booleans and loop through the list until you've tested them all and they were all true or you found one that is false.

Comment: Is the intention here that `masterBool` always be the result of `&&`ing all of the subordinate bool's together? Or could there be a case where some other (`!someNewNotTrue`) logic is applied?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a simple dictionary of bool's and LINQ will do the trick for you:

```
var criteria = new Dictionary<string, bool>{
    {"oneCriterion", true},
    {"anotherOne", true},
    {"andAnotherOne", true}
};

//true!
var masterCriteria = criteria.All(x => x.Value);
Assert.IsTrue(masterCriteria);

criteria.Remove("oneCriterion");
criteria.Add("newCriterion", false);

//false
masterCriteria = criteria.All(x => x.Value);
Assert.IsFalse(masterCriteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends a lot on your implementation, and the frameworks you can use around it. Perhaps you are using a dependency injection framework, in this case, you could implement an interface that handles the decision making, and provide an implementation that implements the current decisions to be made

You could for example use [Microsofts UnityContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507453(v=pandp.30).aspx) and decide to build something like

```
public interface IConditionMaker {
    bool IsConditionTrue();
}
```

and then reference this interface so it gets injected through the DI framework, your class might look like this then

```
public interface IExecutionClass {
    void TakeAction();
}

public class ExecutionClass : IExecutionClass {
    private readonly IConditionMaker _conditionMaker;

    public ExecutionClass(IConditionMaker conditionMaker) {
        _conditionMaker = conditionMaker;
    }

    public void TakeAction() {
        if (_conditionMaker.IsConditionTrue()) {
            // do your action
        }
    }

}
```

You would then make your first implementation like

```
public class ConditionMaker : IConditionMaker {
    public bool IsConditionTrue() {
        bool isTrue = true;
        bool isAlsoTrue = true;
        bool isTrueToo = true;

        return (isTrue && isAlsoTrue && isTrueToo);
    }
}
```

and then register those things through unity, like

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IConditionMaker, ConditionMaker>();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IExecutionClass, ExecutionClass>();
```

Now, each time the IExecutionClass is needed (eg: inside controllers, or at other points), it can will resolve through the injection framework and give you the real implementation, and will also solve the constructor parameter IConditionMaker as ConditionMaker.

If you need to change something later in the code, you might only need to change the ConditionMaker implementation, but the rest of your code can stay the same.

The .net framework has a good example with for example, [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx), where you could simply implement from the `ICommand` interface, and have something like

```
public MyCommand : ICommand {
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute( object parameter ) {
        return true; // always execute, or evaluate parameter and decide, or use injected members and make your decision
    }

    public void Execute( object parameter ) {
        // do your action, knowing that the CanExecute was already executed
    }
}
```

However, it really depends on your situation and framework that can be used. Maybe you are best of with a simple list of [`Predicate<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) which you could then enumerate, like:

```
// say you have some kind of argument, you can pass that argument along
if (predicateList.All(predicate => predicate( argument ))) {
    // all predicates succeeded, do your action
}
```

And then you only need to register/unregister the predicates that apply at that time

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I like the DI solution, though I think in my case I might be better of with a list. I thought a collection might be useful here, too. I'll have to do a bit more research on the Predicate  delegate however

Comment: @Maxwell You have plenty of options, and it really depends on the complexity of your solution and what frameworks you have available, Unity works quite well with MVC, that's why I explained the process a bit. Nothing stops you however from abstracting your needs into interfaces and distinct implementations, as this could be the most flexible approach, and though you might not use a DI framework at the moment, this could change. Till then you could always build the instances yourself and pass in the consructor arguments it can still be flexible like that, to always use the least concrete type